# Impact of custom train_step function in Keras

Tags: keras, tf.keras

I'm having a problem understading how the custom train_step function in keras works and would like to have insights from the community.

My problem: I'm building a network for Face Super Resolution (more specifically, this one: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9428360), and I'm using a custom model to build the logic for it. I have some metrics that I want to plot, when I return all the metrics to plot from the custom train_step function I get very bad results and when I return only the network loss the results are a little bit better (far from perfect, but that's another issue). Examples:

[image: Result when only the network loss is returned]

[image: Results when all the losses are returned]

The first test (image) is returning only the network loss, the second test (image) is returning all metrics that I need to plot.

You can check the commit between the first test and the second to understand better what I'm saying: https://github.com/JoaoPicolo/UFPR-DissertationFSR/commit/6bf171a155b99f64042223942089eec0d2349803

The full code is available at: https://github.com/JoaoPicolo/UFPR-DissertationFSR/tree/main/src/DIDnet

I have already tried changing the train_step return arguments and observe that the results are different when I only change them. Is there any part of Keras' documentation explaining exactly how this impact the network? I wans't able to find.

In the last commit that I referenced I'm also changing the metrics paramater, but I'm sure that it isn't what is impacting the final results since I did previous tests without changing it and got the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found out the problem. It wasn't related to the train_step function, but to the custom callback I used.

It turns out that inside the callback I was overwriting the self.metrics attribute of the Model class, so changing the name of this variable solved my issue. Link to the solution: https://github.com/JoaoPicolo/UFPR-DissertationFSR/commit/eda02729499b4dacd632e826e5fd625339b8f1ac

I'll keep this here for reference if anyone in the future has this error that took me days to solve.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).